# C# + SQL Server - Fastest / Most Efficient way to read new rows into memory

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I have an SQL Server 2008 Database and am using C# 4.0 with Linq to Entities classes setup for Database interaction.

There exists a table which is indexed on a DateTime column where the value is the insertion time for the row. Several new rows are added a second (~20) and I need to effectively pull them into memory so that I can display them in a GUI. For simplicity lets just say I need to show the newest 50 rows in a list displayed via WPF.

I am concerned with the load polling may place on the database and the time it will take to process new results forcing me to become a slow consumer (Getting stuck behind a backlog). I was hoping for some advice on an approach. The ones I'm considering are;

1. Poll the database in a tight loop (~1 result per query)
2. Poll the database every second (~20 results per query)
3. Create a database trigger for Inserts and tie it to an event in C# ([SqlDependency](http://eclipsed4utoo.com/blog/sqldependency-monitor-sql-database/))

I also have some options for access;

1. Linq-to-Entities Table Select
2. Raw SQL Query
3. Linq-to-Entities Stored Procedure

If you could shed some light on the pros and cons or suggest another way entirely I'd love to hear it.

The process which adds the rows to the table is not under my control, I wish only to read the rows never to modify or add. The most important things are to not overload the SQL Server, keep the GUI up to date and responsive and use as little memory as possible... you know, the basics ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little late to the party here, but if you have the feature on your edition of SQL Server 2008, there is a feature known as [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=SQL.100).aspx) that may help.  Basically, you have to enable this feature both for the database and for the specific tables you need to capture.  The built-in Change Data Capture process looks at the transaction log to determine what changes have been made to the table and records them in a pre-defined table structure.  You can then query this table or pull results from the table into something friendlier (perhaps on another server altogether?).  We are in the early stages of using this feature for a particular business requirement, and it seems to be working quite well thus far.

You would have to test whether this feature would meet your needs as far as speed, but it may help maintenance since no triggers are required and the data capture does not tie up your database tables themselves.

Comment: All of the answers were good but this feature I was unaware of and have ended up using in my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than polling the database, maybe you can use the SQL Server Service broker and perform the read from there, even pushing which rows are new.  Then you can select from the table.

The most important thing I would see here is having an index on the way you identify new rows (a timestamp?).  That way your query would select the top entries from the index instead of querying the table every time.

Test, test, test!  Benchmark your performance for any tactic you want to try.  The biggest issues to resolve are how the data is stored and any locking and consistency issues you need to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

If you table is updated constantly with 20 rows a second, then there is nothing better to do that pull every second or every few seconds. As long as you have an efficient way (meaning an index or clustered index) that can retrieve the last rows that were inserted, this method will consume the fewest resources.

IF the updates occur in burst of 20 updates per second but with significant periods of inactivity  (minutes) in between, then you can use SqlDependency (which has absolutely nothing to do with triggers, by the way, read [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) for to udneratand how it actually works). You can mix LINQ with SqlDependency, see [linq2cache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to query to be notified of new data?

You may be better off using push notifications from a Service Bus (eg: [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/)).

Using notifications (i.e events) is almost always a better solution than using polling.